# MeteorJS: Change value of input text

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, coffeescript, pug

I have this code

*product.jade*

```
 a#home(href="{{pathFor 'home'}}") Home
 input#qty.form-control(type="text", value="1", name="qty")
```

*product.coffee*

```
Template['product'].events
    'click #home': (e, template) ->
       text = template.find("#qty")
       ???
       return
```

How do I set the value of qty to 5 every time home is click? I tried to used text.value("5") but error occurred

> Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function.

Any ideas?

Comment: The file is called `product.jade` but the template name is `header`? This is fine, but I just want to be sure which template contains which elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Template.product.events
  'click #home': ->
    $('#qty').val 5
```

Keep in mind that ids should only ever appear once on the page, so `template.find` isn't really necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Template.product.events
  'click #home': (e, template) ->
    template.$('#qty').val 5
```

Or this:

```
Template.product.events
  'click #home': (e) ->
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('#qty').val 5
```